# Alternative to rand() for avoid race conditions?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

> In C, the generation algorithm used by rand is guaranteed to only be
>   advanced by calls to this function. In C++, this constraint is
>   relaxed, and a library implementation is allowed to advance the
>   generator on other circumstances (such as calls to elements of
>   ).

But then over here it says :

> The function accesses and modifies internal state objects, which may
>   cause data races with concurrent calls to rand or srand.
>
> Some libraries provide an alternative function that explicitly avoids
>   this kind of data race: rand_r (non-portable).
>
> C++ library implementations are allowed to guarantee no data races for
>   calling this function.

Ideally I would like to have some kind of "instance" of rand, so that for that instance, and a given seed, I always generate the same sequence of numbers for calls to **THAT instance** . With the current versions it seems that in some platforms, calls by other functions to rand() (perhaps even on different threads), could affect the sequence of numbers generated in my thread by my code.

Is there an alternative, where I can hold on to some kind of "instance", where I am guaranteed to generate a particular sequence, given a seed, and where other calls to different "instances" do not affect it ?

EDIT: For clarity - my code is going to run on multiple different platforms (iOS, Android, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Linux etc), and it isn't possible for me to test every implementation at present. I would just like to implement things based on what is guaranteed by the standard...

Comment: Check out the C++11 random number features: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: @aschepler I don't care very much how "random" the numbers are.. There are so many different engines its going to take a really long time to figure out which one does what I ask in the question..

Comment: Okay, but the new way allows you to store all the state however you want, rather than relying on some global state.

Comment: @aschepler Can you explain which one stores the state ? There are so many different engines its unclear which one to use, and then there is the question of portability (whether the function is even available on all platforms), and the "randomness" / "pseudo randomness" is not so important to me.

Comment: Assuming that you have the library on each platform, I would expect to have the same sequence if you use the algorithm, distribution and seed on each one (for each thread) assuming that you would get the same number of calls...

Comment: @Phil1970 I was trying to use only STL. Some things aren't available on each platform for example - arc4random is there on android studios compiler, and llvm, but visual studio 2013+ compiler doesn't have arc4random... If you are recommending a library, which one would you suggest ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and [std::mt19937](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) to keep a generator with your common seed (all from `<random>` library).

```
std::mt19937 gen(SEED);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(MIN, MAX);
auto random_number = dis(gen);
```

Here, `SEED` is the seed number you want to specify. You can set another seed later with the `.seed` method too:

```
std::mt19937 gen{};
gen.seed(SEED);
```

If you need to generate one, you can use [std::random_device](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) for that:

```
std::random_device rd{};
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
```

The `dis(MIN, MAX)` part sets a range of min and max values this distribution can come up with, which means it will never generate a value bigger than `MAX`, or smaller than `MIN`.

Finally, you can use your generator with this distribution to generate your wanted random values like so: `dis(gen)`. The distribution can take any generator, so if you want other distributions with the same sequence of random numbers, you may make a copy of `gen`, or use the same seed and construct two or more generators.

Comment: Is this part of STL ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay, yes, it's from the standard C++ library.

Comment: Are dis, and gen completely independent of other instances of std::mt19937 and std::uniform_int_distribution ? I couldn't find it in the documentation you linked to...

Comment: Yes, they are. One is a random generator, the other is a random algorithm. Two instances of std::mt19937 are unrelated to one another (i.e. there's no shared data here).

Answer (score 1):

use random() instead of rand().

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MSC30-C.+Do+not+use+the+rand%28%29+function+for+generating+pseudorandom+numbers

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/CON33-C.+Avoid+race+conditions+when+using+library+functions

Comment: Security is not important for my purpose. Can you explain why random is better ? Can I seed it, and get the same sequence ?

Comment: random() is not part of STL .. is there any thing in STL you recommend ?